# Blazor: How to facilitate that a viewmodel is initialized with the correct state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, blazor, solid-principles

If You are familiar with blazor You will know that EditForm components* need a model provided to them. In such case the provided ViewModel is used both for creation of a new entity and an existing one that you pull from the database. In one case therefor the ViewModel has the Id == null and another where it has the Id of the existing entity. What is the best way to let the ViewModel be created?

One could be this with two constructors:

```
    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel(String name, Int32 age)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(name)} is invalid");
            if (age < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(age)} is invalid");

            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        public PersonViewModel(Guid id, String name, Int32 age)
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(id)} is invalid");
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(name)} is invalid");
            if (age < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(age)} is invalid");

            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        public Guid? Id { get; }
        public String Name { get; }
        public Int32 Age { get; }
    }
```

Here there is the repetion of the validation as an issue.

Another one would be with two different static method and making the constructor private, this ofc introduce some disadvantages like you would not be able to inherit the class and use base constructor:

```
    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        private PersonViewModel() { }

        public Guid? Id { get; private set; }
        public String Name { get; init; }
        public Int32 Age { get; init; }

        public static PersonViewModel MakeWithoutId(String name, Int32 age)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(name)} is invalid");
            if (age < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(age)} is invalid");

            return new()
            {
                Name = name,
                Age = age,
            };
        }

        public static PersonViewModel MakeWithId(Guid id, String name, Int32 age)
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(id)} is invalid");

            var vm = PersonViewModel.MakeWithoutId(name, age);
            vm.Id = id;
            return vm;
        }
    }
```

I guess one could say that having the id as private set instead of init is bad and I could have just initialized it from scratch again but in this way I reuse the code and validation from the previous method.
Or should I have two separated ViewModel classes where one inherits or contains the other like NewPersonViewModel and ExistingPersonViewModel?

- Now that i think about it the property used in the EditForm inputs should have the public set, sorry for the mistake I was trying this code in a random file

Comment: Without a `private set;` the validation in the constructor is avoidable. Mappers and Serializers will just set the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the validation code more close to the properties, this way you can use the public setters too.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private Guid? _id;
    private string _name;
    private int _age;

    public Guid? Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == Guid.Empty) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(value)} is invalid");
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(value)} is invalid");
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(value)} is invalid");
            _age = value;
        }
    }

    public PersonViewModel(String name, Int32 age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Guid id, String name, Int32 age)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
    public static PersonViewModel GetInstance(String name, Int32 age)
    {
        return new PersonViewModel(name, age);

    }

    public static PersonViewModel GetInstance(Guid id, String name, Int32 age)
    {
        return new PersonViewModel(id, name, age);
    }
}
```

test

```
var pvm=PersonViewModel.GetInstance("New Name", 20); //ok
var pvm1=PersonViewModel.GetInstance(Guid.NewGuid(), "New Name", -1); //invalid age exception
```

i put an exception because you wanted it Just use data annotations or fluent validation if you need only for  user validation.

or you can create the properties to show error messages, something like this

```
public string AgeErrorMessage {get; private set;}
    
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) AgeErrorMessage=$"{nameof(value)} is invalid";
           else
           {
            AgeErrorMessage=string.Empty;
            _age = value;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can EditForm work with `Name { get; private set; }` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don' t know , you have to try it or  post EditForm too.  But I don't see any problem to change to public.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I updated my answer, now you can use public setters too

Comment: But this will throw InvalidOp in the UI. Not very nice for the User.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You can put any code there.  I put it because you want it in your question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I updated my answer, maybe this then will work for you if you want the validation immediately.